# Create an event for a DataGridViewButtonCell in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, datagrid

I have a DataGridViewButtonColumn, but I need it to respond when clicked so I can execute code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the datagridviewcellcontentclick event. and execute your logic if the button cell was clicked. the following code snippet should give you some idea.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
// find out which column was clicked
if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] == Column1)
{
 //get the value which you want to display
 String customer = (String) dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value;

 // display on the new form.
 Form form2 = new Form();
 form2.Text = customer;
 form2.ShowDialog();

 }
}
```